# Magento 2.3 Product image Urls 404

Tags: magento2

I have a two Magento site both running on M2.3

On one site product details page images are served from pub/media/product. In this case the product images return 404 error. When I check, the product images are saved in pub/media/catalog/product

In the second website the images are served from pub/media/catalog/product which seems to be correct.

The 2 websites use the same theme ultimo.

So why does the first website use wrong image URLs?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: compare both website's .htaccess file in `pub` and root

Comment: @ShoaibMunir I have checked the website's .htaccess file in both pub and root and they are similar

Answer (score 0):

Try to change permission on that folder.

`chmod -R 777 pub/media/catalog`

If you have a CDN purge all product images cache.

I just fixed it that way.